# How to debug AJAX requests? How to know which PHP function is invoked?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm debugging Ajax calls.

How do I know which specific PHP function is called by an ajax call ?

I can only see the request and the javascript code triggering the request, but I dunno how is handled on the request on server side ?

I'm currently inspecting all php code, but I was wondering if there is an easier way..

thanks

Answer (score 3):

An Ajax call does not call a specific function, it merely executes a script. Look at the script, search for its "main" (Whatever name it has in your script) and you'll have the exectued function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a real debug environment and be able to set breakpoints in your php-code, refer to  the zend debugger or xdebug. Both can be controlled with the pdt eclipse-plugin or other IDEs.

If you just want to see some small pieces of information, you can of course just add some echo's or var_dump's to your php-code and then use the firebug firefox extension to view the response to your ajax-requests, which contains the echoed strings.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you make use of [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) and [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/). [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) allows you to log from PHP to FireBug console. In this way you can log anything for example all the queries being run or log from methods/functions.

Answer (score 0):

Just use firebug and after the request is sent, look for the response. e.g. function1 echo foo, function2 echo bar, if it's blank...none of those 2 function was called.

On my end, I'm using Safari and finding both request / response from an ajax call to a PHP script is a breeze.

Comment: yeah but you still have to guess to which php file the function is included, and which is the function, right ? In Firebug I see the post and the answer, but I don't see who is generating the answer

Answer (score 0):

Debugging using Firefox's addon FireBug, you can check out the request and response data content easily.

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/code/216729

So by right, Ajax cannot access remote web server content, so you need the proxy page in the middle of the whole architecture flow.

So which means:
[Within Same Server]
PHP page using AJAX -> Web Services / Web Server that contains your response functions

[Within 2 Servers, Connecting to Remote Server]
PHP page using AJAX -> PHP Proxy Page -> Web Services / Web Server that contains your response functions

So the overall proxy page acting like a "middle-man" to connect to remote site.

[IMPORTANT]
Don't confuse router proxy and proxy page, but have the same theory but it is different thing.