# ISSET error sending Javascript array to PHP using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, jquery

I want to send a Javascript array to PHP using AJAX.  This seems very simple code, but I am getting the "No isset" message.

```
<?php 

if (isset($_REQUEST['activitiesArray'])) {
echo 'YES isset';   
}else{
echo 'No isset';
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


var activities = ["thing1", "thing2", "thing3"];

$.ajax({        
   type: "POST",
   url: "JavatoDBase.php",
   data: { activitiesArray : activities },
     success: function() {
     $("#lengthQuestion").fadeOut('slow');        
     }
 });
```

Safari displays the following, which suggests the POST is operating

[image]

Comment: what happens when you dump the whole request back to client?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug AJAX requests? How to know which PHP function is invoked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153019/how-to-debug-ajax-requests-how-to-know-which-php-function-is-invoked)

Comment: Look into the request which data is actually submitted and how.

Comment: Did you try posting a json instead of an array?

Comment: Thanks guys.  I did try sending a small text string, but same error message.  Also.  The PHP is in the same file as the javascript i.e. "JavatoDBase.php" so I don't think I'm calling another PHP function

Comment: Can you do a print_r for $myArray = $_REQUEST['activitiesArray '] ??

Comment: It looks like the question is an edit version (which helps) - if so, as the above appears fine, check you don't have a second "data" element in the ajax call. That's got me once or twice.

Comment: Stringify your javascript object (json) with var activities = JSON.stringify(your_array);
Decode your data on the server-side processing: $data = json_decode($_POST);

Comment: I ran your code in my environment and got "YES isset". So I don't know why what you posted isn't working.

Comment: you are sending back an invalid html page with text before the doctype, create a separate file to handle the post. Likely something else wrong in your code. Also wrap your jquery in ready handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make an ajax request, you should return something that you can use in the js to determine how it went.  You also only want to load the response, not the entire page html and all.

Try this:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_REQUEST['activitiesArray'])) {
  echo json_encode(
    array('status' => true)
  );
  exit(0);
}else{
echo 'No isset';
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var activities = ["thing1", "thing2", "thing3"];

  $.ajax({        
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: { activitiesArray : activities },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.status === true) {
        alert('rad');
      }
      else {
        alert('bad');
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  All the above code was help is the PHP file (I started with PHP and HTML followed).  I then split the PHP into its own (PHP suffix) file and the HTML into its own (HTML suffix) file.  It worked like a charm.  Thanks for your help.